# When select two item at the same time in recycle view application crash,how can i solve this?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

```
 public class BrandsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BrandsAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
        private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
        int itemLayout = R.layout.brand_item;
        private List<Brand> mValues;
        private List<Brand> contactListFiltered;
        private LoadImage loadImage;
        Context mcontext;
        public BrandsAdapter(Context context, List<Brand> items, int i, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
            mValues = items;
            loadImage = LoadImage.getInstance(context);
            contactListFiltered = items;
            mListener = listener;
            if (i == 1) {
                itemLayout = R.layout.brand_item2;
            }

            mcontext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mItem = contactListFiltered.get(position);
            holder.mNameView.setText(holder.mItem.getBrandname());

            PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(mcontext).load(contactListFiltered.get(position).getBrandimage()).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).into(holder.mLogoView);

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(v -> {            
                    if (null != mListener) {
                        mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                    }          

            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return contactListFiltered.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    String charString = charSequence.toString();
                    if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                        contactListFiltered = mValues;
                    } else {
                        List<Brand> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Brand row : mValues) {
                            // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                            // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                            if (row.getBrandname().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                                filteredList.add(row);
                            }
                        }
                        contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                    }
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                    contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<Brand>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
             final View mView;
             final TextView mNameView;
             final ImageView mLogoView;
             final ProgressBar progressBar;
             Brand mItem;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mNameView =  view.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
                mLogoView =  view.findViewById(R.id.brand_img);
                progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mNameView.getText() + "'";
            }
        }
    }
```

when i clicked two item at the same time the app calls the interface method two times `mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);`

It does

```
findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_support).navigate(R.id.action_brandsFragment_to_devicesFragment, bundle);
```

StackTrace

```
 Process: com.unicomg.proserve, PID: 25752
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.unicomg.proserve:id/action_brandsFragment_to_devicesFragment is unknown to this NavController
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:789)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:716)
        at com.unicomg.proserve.ui.main.fragments.brands.BrandsFragment.lambda$initBrands$4$BrandsFragment(BrandsFragment.java:75)
        at com.unicomg.proserve.ui.main.fragments.brands.-$$Lambda$BrandsFragment$pny4rYwzqdcDuB9NcgZbiyK2Ick.onListFragmentInteraction(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.unicomg.proserve.ui.main.fragments.brands.BrandsAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$BrandsAdapter(BrandsAdapter.java:74)
        at com.unicomg.proserve.ui.main.fragments.brands.-$$Lambda$BrandsAdapter$NWl2ZJhVqEGxSaOEOsJQCc9r7Po.onClick(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because on the first tap it switches to `DevicesFragment`, and the action doesn't exist in that graph when the second tap is handled.

You could add this check:

```
if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.devicesFragment) {
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_brandsFragment_to_devicesFragment)
}
```

or this one:

```
navController.currentDestination?.getAction(R.id.action_brandsFragment_to_devicesFragment)?.let { 
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_brandsFragment_to_devicesFragment)
}
```

and you can also make them extension functions if you want to